# document.getElementById in array

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elem = document.getElementById("test");
    elem.id = 1;
    alert(elem.id);
</script>
```

Can I save elem and elem.id in array?
I don't know how.
I tried:

```
var elem[0] = document.getElementById("test");
elem[0].id = 1;
alert(elem[0].id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it. First you need to *create* the array:

```
var elements = [];
```

*Then* you can put items in it:

```
elements[0] = document.getElementById("test");
elements[0].id = 1;
alert(elements[0].id);
```

---

You can also use the [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method of Array objects. Also note: the `id` property of an element is a string, and as such your number will be converted to the string `"1"`.